# "As much as"—meaning in the sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The job market is not a physical place **as much as** a concept demonstrating the competition and interplay between different labor forces.

I think "but" is more suitable to use in the  place of **as much as**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of nuance.

"Not A but B" strictly means yes to B, no to A.

"Not A as much as B" may be an euphemistic way to say the same, but the straightforward meaning is "less of A and more of B", i. e. to some extent, A is still true, but B is more significant.

Since job market is not a physical place at all, "but" would certainly be a good choice here. I'd deem it stylistically better, too. The way it's phrased isn't wrong as such, but it's wordy and comes across as overly formal.